# CMakelist include subfolders

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I can't figure out how to import my source files, which are in a different directory. The structure of my project looks like this:

```
root
- src
   - core
      App.h
      App.cpp
      CMakelist.txt
   CMakelist.txt
main.cpp
CMakelist.txt
```

My main CMakelist under root looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(edu)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

## add subdirectory with source files
add_subdirectory(src)

add_executable(edu main.cpp)
```

My CMakelist under src looks like this:

```
add_subdirectory(core)
```

And finaly my CMakelist under core looks like this:

```
set(all_src
        App.h
        App.cpp
        )

target_sources(core ${all_src})
```

But it doesn't work, I get an error:

> Cannot specify sources for target "core" which is not built by this project

How do I fix it? My project is getting quite large and it would be convenient to put all the files in different directories instead of stacking them in add_executable

Thx!

Comment: Where do you define the core target?

Comment: @stephen-newell core target? the files in core are part of my project, they are not a library or anything else, Do I really need that definition?

Comment: if you do not want to use a separate library for core, you could, in src/CMakeLists.txt: `set(core_srcs core/App.cpp core/App.h)` and then `add_executable(edu main.cpp ${core_srcs}`. This lets you organize your CMakeLists.txt by module and keep your sources in different directories, without exploding the number of CMakeLists and libraries

Comment: @peter Thank you, will this help me solve the problem of imports? because the files in the folders lost global imports -  include

Comment: Yes, it is just like listing every file in one add_executable.  You're just referring to them in their subdirectories.  The variables just let you list the sources separately and by module.

Comment: @Peter thx, what about if I have another folder? like 'core' for example 'core-abc'

Comment: created an answer based on my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a separate library for `core`, you can use the following structure in `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# core sources
set(core_srcs core/App.cpp core/App.h)

# aux sources
set(aux_srcs aux/stuff.cpp aux/stuff.h)

add_executable(edu main.cpp ${core_srcs} ${aux_srcs})
```

This lets you organize your CMakeLists.txt by module and keep your sources in different directories, without exploding the number of CMakeLists and sublibraries.

Comment: first of all my main.cpp not in src dir? secound thing cpp files in dir dont see imports in another dirs

Comment: you can "namespace" your includes by using the subdirectory name: #include <aux/something.h>, which isn't a bad way to be more explicit about what you're doing.  Or add all your subdirectories to the include path.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that you never created a target called core. You need to either use either `add_executable` or `add_library` to create a target to add files to. You never created a target named core, so you're trying to add these files to something that doesn't exist.

---

What might help here is implementing Modern CMake, which is an approach to CMake looking at it more akin to a language than a tool. Here's a good beginners guide to structuring your project that should make it far easier to use CMake. If you want to separate your project into modules, I'd recommend making this it's own confined library within your project that will then be included into your main executable as a library. IF you just want to organize your source code, then try the method keeping separate `src` and `include` directories. It makes it far easier to organize and sort your code~

Here's some references for Modern CMake:

https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

https://hsf-training.github.io/hsf-training-cmake-webpage/aio/index.html

https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1

Comment: but as i say core is not lib and i dont have "start point" main file in core src dir, may be u help me and show example how my list file can look

Comment: The character limit is generous enough that you can type complete sentences.

Comment: @sweenish I said that maybe the answer author could show me an example on my project how the structure and code of the CMakelist files should be organized.

Comment: @goGOgo, the first link has explanation on separating source and include directories and the such. the only example I can readily provide is one of my own projects: https://github.com/macr0nerd/libeztp